# Can someone explain the recursion function in attachment?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a totally newbie who's learning python 3.x by myself. I'm right now doing a recursion practice and I have a question about it. Below is the segment of my recursion function. This functions works well. However, when I took the first if statement out, the recursion function stopped working. Can someone explain why? I just don't see why the first IF statement if neccessary. Thank you .

```
def count_recursive(sentence):  
      if not sentence:  
        return 0  
    return (1 if sentence[0] in 'aeiouAEIOU' else 0)+count_recursive(sentence[1:])

def main():  
    print("Recursion =", count_recursive(sentence))

main()
```

Comment: When writing a recursive function, the function needs to know when to stop calling itself. The `if not sentence: return 0` block is that base case. Without it, you will continuously slice 1 item off of sentence and call `count_recursive` again and again. BTW: `not sentence` will evaluate to True if `sentence` is a False-y item. IE if it is `None`, an empty `str`, an empty `list`, etc...

Comment: It could be helpful to take a small example string and work through how this function works *by hand*. Try and see what happens with and without the first if statement.

Comment: So what does this if not sentence saying? Is it saying if input string is not valid?

Comment: This was what I did. I took that if statement out and I got an error

Comment: Yes, you probably got an `IndexError` because you eventually pass an empty string to `count_recursive`. Then, you try to index it with `sentence[0]` and that raises the Error. You enter the first if statement (and return 0) **if** sentence is an empty string, in this context. Personally, I would change it to `if sentence == "":` since that is more **explicit** in what is actually happening.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you for explaining

Comment: One more question, when I call count_recursive(sentence[1:]), does it check from index 1 to the end of input string? My understading is each element in string list sentence from index 1 to the end goes through the count_recursive function to be checked. So if this is the case, won't the recursion stop after the end of input string because I specified the function to go through sentence[1:]? Why did it give me a index error?

Comment: Try this in your own interpreter. `sentence = "hello"; print(sentence[1:])`. You'll see that it prints `"ello"`. Your function works because it is recursively stripping off the first element, and sending the rest of the string back into the function. Every time it matches a condition (your `aeiouAEIOU` part), it adds 1 to the number that is to be returned. Try adding `print(sentence)` to beginning of your function and you'll see how it gets called every time.

Comment: So if I specify a certain range of sentence[1:10], this recursion will automatically stop at 10th index without having to use a base case. Am I correct?

Comment: No. The slicing you are doing with `1:10` has *nothing* to do with recursion. All it is doing is taking a segment from your string. The recursion in your function works because you are incrementally removing one element from sentence and passing that to your function. Maybe take a step back and look up some resources about string slicing and indexing, because I think there's a mis-understanding with how that's working.